# How do I let AppleScript choose any type of file?

Tags: applescript

I'm making a script that makes encrypting files easier and at the beginning portion I have this:

```
display dialog "Choose where your file is located."
set directory to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop))
display dialog "Choose your file."
choose file with prompt "File Name:"
set filepath to result
```

When it asking for a file, is there any other way that I can make it be able to choose anything? (Folders, images...)

Answer (score 6):

### **Can't be done**

The following are different ways to prompt for files. There is no way, **in pure Apple Script**, to prompt for Files **or** Folders at the same time.

**Select File**:

```
set directory to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop))
```

**Select Files**:

```
set directory to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop) with multiple selections allowed)
```

**Select Folder**:

```
set directory to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop))
```

**Select Folders**:

```
set directory to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop) with multiple selections allowed)
```

**Select Specific Types of Files:**

> ### Prompting for a Specific Type of File
>
> If your script requires specific types of files for processing, you
>   can use the choose file command’s optional of type parameter to
>   provide a list of acceptable types. Types may be specified as
>   extension strings without the leading period (such as "jpg" or "png")
>   or as uniform type identifiers (such as "public.image" or
>   "com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages"). Listing 26-3 and Listing 26-4 show
>   how to prompt for an image.

For Images:

```
set directory to POSIX path of (choose file of type {"public.image"} with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop) with multiple selections allowed)
```

**Sources: [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/PromptforaFileorFolder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH81-SW1)**

---

**Using AppleScriptObjC you can ask for either Files or Folders. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551206/7886229) answer (if the linked answer helped, please upvote the linked Q&A):**

> No, you can't do it with "choose file" or "choose folder" verbs, but
>   choosing a file *or* folder (or multiple files/folders) is supported
>   by the underlying `NSOpenPanel`.  So you can do it with
>   AppleScriptObjC. Here's an example using [ASObjCRunner][1] (derived
>   from [here][2]):
>
> ```
> script chooseFilesOrFolders
>   tell current application's NSOpenPanel's openPanel()
>       setTitle_("Choose Files or Folders") -- window title, default is "Open"
>       setPrompt_("Choose") -- button name, default is "Open"
>
>       setCanChooseFiles_(true)
>       setCanChooseDirectories_(true)
>       setAllowsMultipleSelection_(true) -- remove if you only want a single file/folder
>
>       get its runModal() as integer -- show the panel
>       if result is current application's NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton then error number -128 -- cancelled
>       return URLs() as list
>   end tell
> end script
>
> tell application "ASObjC Runner"
>   activate
>   run the script {chooseFilesOrFolders} with response
> end tell
> ```
>
> ASObjCRunner converts a `NSArray` of `NSURL` objects into an
>   AppleScript list of `file`s; the results can look something like:
>
> ```
> {file "Macintosh HD:Users:nicholas:Desktop:fontconfig:", file "Macintosh HD:Users:nicholas:Desktop:form.pdf"}
> ```
>
> [1]: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner.html
>   [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125563/

---

You could use a dialog box prompting a user to select what they would like to encrypt.

```
display dialog "Select a type to Encrypt" buttons {"File(s)", "Folder(s)"}
set a to the button returned of the result
if a is "File(s)" then
    set directory to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop) with multiple selections allowed)
else
    set directory to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "File Location:" default location (path to desktop) with multiple selections allowed)
end if
```

---

Lastly, check out my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327555/263848) for a way to encrypt files with Apple Script and Automator.